# yas-new-snippet always duplicates the selected input. What might be causing it?

Tags: yasnippet

I've experienced this issue for some time. It's not a blocker but it is a bit annoying.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Select a region that you want to extract into YASnippet snippet("foo bar").
Eval `yas-new-snippet`.

You are redirected to a new buffer +new-snippet+ with the following content:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: 
# key: 
# --
// foo bar
// foo bar
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: 
# key: 
# --
// foo bar
```

> pkg-info-package-version yasnippet 20200604.246

Comment: I'm using the same version of yas and have the correct behavior. You may need to find more about what in you config is causing this before anyone can give any advice.

Comment: @PanJunjie潘俊杰 thanks for the input. I'll continue investigating it, it could probably be something that activates it twice in my emacs/spacemacs config.

Comment: You could `edebug-defun` function `yas-new-snippet` to find the reasons. On my config `yas-new-snippet` is working like expected.

Comment: Oh, and you can `trace-function` the function you suspect being running twice, should be easier than learning how to debug (which I never learned myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably set `yas-wrap-around-region` to `t`, this will insert your region at the snippet placeholder `$0`. Calling `yas-new-snippet` will expand a snippet to create your new snippet: `yas-new-snippet-default`. If you look at the default value, it contains `$0` and `yas-selected-text`, and now both will be filled with your region.

I suggested a fix in this PR: https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/1102

As a workaround, you could advice the function like this:

```
(defun yas-new-snippet-fix-region (func &rest args)
  (let ((yas-wrap-around-region nil))
    (apply func args)))
(advice-add 'yas-new-snippet :around #'yas-new-snippet-fix-region)
```

Comment: you were right - yas-wrap-around-regions is true indeed. Just followed your pull request. Hopefully it will be merged soon. Thanks